# Delphi XE2 64bit: record pointer, invalid typecast

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

How would I recode this to compile on 64-bit for Delphi XE2?

On the first code I get an error size is too large over 2gb.

On the second, Invalid Typecast on: if int64(TMethod(FOnChangeOO[i1])) = int64(TMethod(changeEvent)) then

1)
    TExtBool    = (no, yes, other);

```
  TAByte          = array [0..maxInt      -1] of byte;
  TAShortInt      = array [0..maxInt      -1] of shortInt;
  TAChar          = array [0..maxInt div sizeOf(Char)-1] of Char;
  TAAnsiChar      = array [0..maxInt      -1] of AnsiChar;
  TAWideChar      = array [0..maxInt shr 1-1] of WideChar;
  TABoolean       = array [0..maxInt      -1] of boolean;
  TAExtBool       = array [0..maxInt      -1] of TExtBool;
  TAWord          = array [0..maxInt shr 1-1] of word;
  TASmallInt      = array [0..maxInt shr 1-1] of smallInt;
  TACardinal      = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of cardinal;
  TAInteger       = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of integer;
  TAPointer       = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of pointer;
  TAString        = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of string;
  TAAnsiString    = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of AnsiString;
  TAWideString    = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of WideString;
  TAUnicodeString = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of UnicodeString;
  TAIUnknown      = array [0..maxInt shr 2-1] of IUnknown;
  TAInt64         = array [0..maxInt shr 3-1] of int64;
```

2)

```
TMethod = record code, data: pointer; end;
  TIListChangeEventOO = procedure (const list: ICustomBasicList; const item: IBasic;
                                   beforeChange: boolean;
                                   changeType: TChangeType; oldIndex, index: integer) of object;
  ICustomBasicList = interface (IList) ['{EE6D35A0-5F85-11D3-A52D-00005A180D69}']
  TChangeType = (lctUnchanged, lctChanged, lctNew, lctDeleted);
 IBasic = interface ['{53F8CE42-2C8A-11D3-A52D-00005A180D69}']


procedure TICustomBasicList.RegisterChangeEvent(changeEvent: TIListChangeEventOO);
var i1 : integer;
begin
  FSection.Enter;
  try
    if CheckValid then begin
      for i1 := 0 to high(FOnChangeOO) do
        if int64(TMethod(FOnChangeOO[i1])) = int64(TMethod(changeEvent)) then
          exit;
      i1 := Length(FOnChangeOO);
      SetLength(FOnChangeOO, i1 + 1);
      FOnChangeOO[i1] := changeEvent;
    end;
  finally FSection.Leave end;
end;

function TICustomBasicList.UnregisterChangeEvent(changeEvent: TIListChangeEvent) : boolean;
var i1, i2 : integer;
begin
  result := false;
  FSection.Enter;
  try
    i2 := high(FOnChange);
    for i1 := i2 downto 0 do
      if @FOnChange[i1] = @changeEvent then begin
        FOnChange[i1] := FOnChange[i2];
        dec(i2);
        result := true;
        FSuccess := true;
      end;
    if result then SetLength(FOnChange, i2 + 1)
    else           SetLastError(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND);
  finally FSection.Leave end;
end;
```

Comment: Would be much nicer just to be able to use indexing on a pointer rather than have to pfaff around with stupid fixed size array type declarations

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) Instead of "shr 1/2/3" you should always use SizeOf(T) because "shr 2 = div 4" is not equal to "div SizeOf(Pointer)" in 64 bit. The same for UnicodeString, WideString, IUnknown, ...

2) TMethod is a record with two pointers. In 32 bit, the two pointers need 8 bytes (32bit * 2). In 64 bit, the two pointers need 16 bytes (64bit * 2). And an Int64 can't hold 128 bit. So you now have to compare the two fields directly instead of casting it.

```
if (TMethod(FOnChangeOO[i1]).Data = TMethod(changeEvent).Data) and
   (TMethod(FOnChangeOO[i1]).Code = TMethod(changeEvent).Code) then
```

Comment: About point 1, all those shr in arrays type indexes are made to define some array storing up to maxInt bytes. This does not make sense any more in 64 bit mode, in which an array can store more than maxInt bytes. IMHO you should leave it as such and force the compiler not to use Range Checking.